# How to extract multiple JSON Objects into String

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I am reading multiple `JSONObject` from a file and converting into a string using `StringBuilder`.

These are the JSON Objects.

```
{"Lng":"-1.5908601","Lat":"53.7987816"}
{"Lng":"-2.5608601","Lat":"54.7987816"}
{"Lng":"-3.5608601","Lat":"55.7987816"}
{"Lng":"-4.5608601","Lat":"56.7987816"}
{"Lng":"-5.560837","Lat":"57.7987816"}
{"Lng":"-6.5608294","Lat":"58.7987772"}
{"Lng":"-7.5608506","Lat":"59.7987823"}
```

How to convert into a string?

Actual code is:-

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            msg.Log(e.toString());
        }

        String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
        //msg.Log(contentsAsString);
```

I tried this code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(contentsAsString);

Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
  while(iter.hasNext())
    {
       String key = iter.next();
         try{
             Object value = json.get(key);
             msg.Log("Value :- "+ value);
         }catch(JSONException e)
          {
              //error
          }
    }
```

It just gives first object. How to loop them?

Comment: What is contentsAsString?

Comment: but you already have it in a string format in your stringbuilder, what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Joel - contentAsString is a list of objects as shown above, which is in a string format.

Comment: faljbour - I want them to be in a separate string variable to use them for example. 

`for(int i=0; i<=json.length(); i++)
{
String lat = json.getString("Lat");
String lng = json.getString("Lng");

Log.i("TAG", lat + lng)
}

i want to get those separate values into a  string to use them.`

Comment: @faljbour - sry i cant make them in a proper format in comment.

Comment: @Gaj create new Object that holds 2 strings?

Comment: What is the type of contentAsString exactly? List<JSONObject> ? List<String> ? String?

Comment: instead of using string builder, use a string array that contain each line from the file, then loop through each string line from the array and construct a json object for it, then you will have an array of JSON objects that you can get your lat, long values from

Comment: @poss, @Ma Kro - I have an app which randomly append an object (`{"Lng":"-1.5908601","Lat":"53.7987816"}` into a file without separated by comma. What I am doing here is, I am reading the whole data using `StringBuilder` and trying to convert and separate using a loop.

Comment: With that format, you should use a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`. Since you only have lat and lng keys. And you need to separate each of those values by a comma `,`.

Comment: sure, see my answer, I did not try to compile it to see if it has any syntax errors, but let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and see how it works for you,

```
BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));

ArrayList<JSONObject> contentsAsJsonObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
while(true)
{
  String str = in.readLine();
  if(str==null)break;
  contentsAsJsonObjects.add(new JSONObject(str));
}

for(int i=0; i<contentsAsJsonObjects.size(); i++) 
{ 
  JSONObject json = contentsAsJsonObjects.get(i);
  String lat = json.getString("Lat"); 
  String lng = json.getString("Lng"); 
  Log.i("TAG", lat + lng) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do is you are loading multiple JSON objects into one JSON object. This does not make sense -- it is logical that only the first object is parsed, the parser does not expect anything after the first `}`. Since you want to loop over the loaded objects, you should load those into a JSON array.

If you can edit the input file, convert it to the array by adding braces and commas

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

If you cannot, append the braces to the beginning of the `StringBuilder` and append comma to each loaded line. Consider additional condition to eliminate exceptions caused by inpropper input file.

Finally you can create JSON array from string and loop over it with this code

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(contentsAsString);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

}
```